# Express-handlebars says engine is not defined, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-handlebars

I installed express-handlebars and i tried this

```
const express = require("express");
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const app = express();

app.engine('.hbs', engine({defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

and I get ReferenceError: engine is not defined

Comment: Because it isn't.

Comment: How come it isn't shouldn't it work since I required express-handlebars

Answer (score 1):

I changed from

```
app.engine('.hbs', engine({defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'}));
```

to

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs.engine({defaultLayout: 'main', extname: '.hbs'}));
```

and it worked